# can you help me understand how this code working i am very starter in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am looking up some Haskell exercises with answers.
This is the exercise:

> Assume that you have a function `rainfall` which computes the rainfall in your city for a given week (where weeks are numbered from 1 and upwards)
>
> ```
> type WeekNumber = Int
> rainfall :: WeekNumber -> Double    -- assume this function exists
> ```
>
> Complete the definition of the following function:
>
> ```
> mostRain :: WeekNumber -> Double
> mostRain n | n < 1     = 0
>            | otherwise =                       -- (complete this case)
> ```
>
> Your solution must be recursive. Hint: The function max may be useful. Note that you do not have to provide a definition for the function `rainfall`.

The answer:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import Test.QuickCheck
-- 1 ----------------
type WeekNumber = Int
rainfall :: WeekNumber -> Double
rainfall n = fromIntegral (n `mod` 7) * 3.9

mostRain :: WeekNumber -> Double
mostRain n | n < 1     = 0
           | otherwise =  rainfall n `max` mostRain (n - 1)
```

I really hoping that someone can help explain to me how they come up with this number 3.9 `` (n `mod` 7) * 3.9 ``

and what actually happens here `` otherwise =  rainfall n `max` mostRain (n - 1) ``?

Comment: What is the first bit that's unclear about `otherwise =  rainfall n \`max\` mostRain (n - 1)`?

Comment: My guess is that the rainfall function is just some arbitrary numbers for generating sample data

Comment: I don't understand why they subtract 1 from n winch is the week number ?

Comment: @HaskellNewbie  It wouldn't terminate otherwise.  Imagine a C loop of `for(i=n; i >= 1 ; i = i) { ... }`.  Since `i` isn't decremented (or `n` in the Haskell loop) it's not going to terminate.

Comment: Thank you!!!! with each comment and answer i have learned something new!!! :) :) <3 <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as @AJFarmar points out, writing the `rainfall` function wasn't part of the exercise.  The answer just provides an arbitrary definition so you can test the solution, and the number 3.9 was just pulled out of thin air to make the rainfall amounts seem "interesting":

```
> rainfall 1
3.9
> rainfall 2
7.8
>
```

You don't really need to understand what the expression:

```
fromIntegral (n `mod` 7) * 3.9
```

does to understand the solution, but  if you're interested, it takes the input integer `n`, calculates `` n `mod` 7 `` (which is the remainder when `n` is divided by 7, so it turns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 into 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3), and converts the result from an integer to a double before multiplying by 3.9.  So, for example, this gives amounts of rainfall for weeks 1 to 10 that look like this:

```
> map rainfall [1..10]
[3.9,7.8,11.7,15.6,19.5,23.4,0.0,3.9,7.8,11.7]
>
```

To understand the part of the solution after `otherwise`, first let's rewrite it to get rid of the special backtick notation:

```
mostRain :: WeekNumber -> Double
mostRain n | n < 1     = 0
           | otherwise =  max (rainfall n) (mostRain (n - 1))
```

This definition says that the calculation of the most rain seen in weeks 1 to n, namely `mostRain n`, will be defined as `0` if `n < 1` and by the following expression otherwise:

```
max (rainfall n) (mostRain (n - 1))
```

This expression evaluates the maximum of two numbers, the value of `rainfall n` (i.e., the rainfall in week `n`) and the value of `mostRain (n - 1)`.  This is a recursive call which will calculate the most rain seen in weeks 1 to `n-1`.

So, this is really saying that the most rain from weeks 1 to n is defined to be the maximum of (1) the amount of rain in week n and (2) the most rain seen in the previous weeks.  Alternatively, you can think of it as performing a calculation in steps like this:

```
mostRain 3
= max (rainfall 3) (mostRain 2)
= max (rainfall 3) (max (rainfall 2) (mostRain 1))
= max (rainfall 3) (max (rainfall 2) (max (rainfall 1) (mostRain 0))
= max (rainfall 3) (max (rainfall 2) (max (rainfall 1) 0)
```

and if we fill in the simulated rainfall amounts, you can see how it ultimately calculates the maximum:

```
= max 11.7 (max 7.8 (max 3.9 0)
= max 11.7 (max 7.8 3.9)
= max 11.7 7.8
= 11.7
```

Comment: Thank you so much all of you who give some time and satt there explaining to me step by step :) :) :) :) I really appreciate your help and I am so grateful to find this website!! Haskell is so difficult and complicated and it made me hate programming, I am a newbie in all programming languages in general! I have applied the code and tried mostRain from 1 to 50 randomly after 5th week all the results are the same mostRain 6
23.4. so I understand that week 6 is the most raining in a whole year?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that it says this in the description:

> `rainfall :: WeekNumber -> Double    -- assume this function exists`

That is to say, **you're not actually expected to define `rainfall`.** The definition they give in the solution is an example definition - the number 3.9 is entirely arbitrary. Ignore it.

You're only supposed to define `mostRain`, and so that's the part you should be paying attention to.

Comment: Great now I know from you that the number 3.9 is arbitrary. and they already defined rainfall . but Ii don't understand why they subtract 1 from n the week-number?

Comment: Are you referring to this: `otherwise =  rainfall n \`max\` mostRain (n - 1)`? It's just saying that the biggest daily rainfall after n days is the greater of: the rainfall on day n, and the previous daily max (that is, the one after n-1 days). [I'm also a relative newbie at Haskell, and I really don't like that the solution has used `max` as an infix function. Clearly it's allowed but I don't really see why, and I think it makes it a bit less readable.]

Comment: @RobinZigmond On infix `max`: yup, that's not great indeed.